# is a windows userspace filesystem the best option?

Tags: c, windows, filesystems

I want to create a virtual folder of run-time generated links. What i mean by run-time is that the location of the link is determined by the result of a query. I want all programs to be able to access the folder, however. Therfore, i think that a namespace extension is not adequate enough. However, a full on filesystem for simple links seems like overkill. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you decided that you need to expose the links as a filesystem, then user-mode filesystem is the obvious choice. But the question is *what for* you need the links to be represented as files. Do you need to expose content behind the URLs as files? Or do you just need to have some hierarchy of links?

Comment: The links need to be hard links. I.e. as though it were actually the file.

Comment: @chacham15 So you need to expose the data behind the links, right? Then yes, user-mode filesystem is the best option. In Windows the toolkits are Dokan and our Callback File System (see comparison here: http://www.eldos.com/cbfs/no-dokan.php ).